# Android : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, audiorecord

I am trying to record audio, after that should play record immediately. Where I am going wrong. Please help me out. I am not getting. showing null pointer exception...

Here is the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Audio_testActivity extends Activity {
private String LOG_TAG = null;

/* variables which are required to generate and manage the UI of the App */
// private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
private Button recordBtn, stopBtn, playBtn;

/*
 * variables which are required for the actual functioning of the recording
 * and playing
 */
private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private AudioTrack player = null;
private AudioManager audioManager = null;
private int recorderBufSize, recordingSampleRate;
private int trackBufSize;
private short[] audioData;
private boolean isRecording = false, isPlaying = false;
private Thread startRecThread;

private AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener posUpdateListener;

/**
 * constructor method for initializing the variables
 */
public Audio_testActivity() {
    super();
    LOG_TAG = "Constructor";
    recorderBufSize = recordingSampleRate = trackBufSize = 0;

    // init function will initialize all the necessary variables ...
    init();

    if (recorder != null && player != null) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "recorder and player initialized");
        audioData = new short[recorderBufSize / 2]; // since we r reading
                                                    // shorts

    } else {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem inside init function ");
    }
    posUpdateListener = new AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener() {
        int numShortsRead = 0;

        @Override
        public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord rec) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // String LOG_TAG = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "inside position listener");
            audioData = new short[recorderBufSize / 2]; // divide by 2 since
                                                        // now we are
                                                        // reading shorts
            numShortsRead = rec.read(audioData, 0, audioData.length);
            player.write(audioData, 0, numShortsRead);

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Marker Reached");
        }
    };
    // listener will be called every time 160 frames are reached
    recorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(160);
    recorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(posUpdateListener);

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "inside constructor");
}

private void init() {
    LOG_TAG = "initFunc";
    // int[] mSampleRates = new int[] { 8000, 11025, 22050, 44100 };
    short audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    // for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
    this.recordingSampleRate = AudioTrack
            .getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " +
        // audioFormat);
        int bufrSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
                this.recordingSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                audioFormat);

        // lets find out the minimum required size for AudioTrack
        int audioTrackBufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
                this.recordingSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                audioFormat);

        if (bufrSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE
                && bufrSize != AudioRecord.ERROR) {
            // check if we can instantiate and have a success
            if (audioTrackBufSize >= bufrSize) {
                this.recorderBufSize = audioTrackBufSize;
            } else {
                this.recorderBufSize = bufrSize;
            }

            AudioRecord rec = new AudioRecord(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT,
                    this.recordingSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    audioFormat, this.recorderBufSize);

            if (rec != null
                    && rec.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {

                // storing variables for future use . . .
                // this.recordingSampleRate = rate;
                // this.recorderBufSize = bufrSize;

                Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                        "Returning..(rate:channelConfig:audioFormat:recorderBufSize)"
                                + this.recordingSampleRate + ":"
                                + AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO + ":"
                                + audioFormat + ":" + this.recorderBufSize);

                // Now create an instance of the AudioTrack
                // int audioTrackBufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(rate,
                // AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, audioFormat);

                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Audio Record / Track / Final buf size :"
                        + bufrSize + "/ " + audioTrackBufSize + "/ "
                        + this.recorderBufSize);

                this.player = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        this.recordingSampleRate,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, audioFormat,
                        this.recorderBufSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                this.recorder = rec;
                this.player.stop();
                this.player.flush();
                this.player.setPlaybackRate(this.recordingSampleRate);
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                this.recordingSampleRate + "Exception, keep trying.", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, this.recordingSampleRate + "Some Exception!!", e);
    }
    // for loop for channel config ended here. . . .
    // for loop for audioFormat ended here. . .
    // }// for loop for sampleRate
    return;
}

private void startPlaying() {
    LOG_TAG = "startPlaying";

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "start Playing");
}

private void stopPlaying() {
    LOG_TAG = "stopPlaying";

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "stop Playing");
}

private void startRecording() {
    LOG_TAG = "startRecording";

    /* start a separate recording thread from here . . . */
    startRecThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            android.os.Process
                    .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
            // String LOG_TAG = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            if (recorder.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
                recorder.startRecording();
            }
            // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "running" +recorder.getRecordingState());
            while (recorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
                recorder.read(audioData, 0, audioData.length);
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for 2s
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("run Method", "recorder thread is interrupted");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
    player.flush();
    player.play();
    startRecThread.start();

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "start Recording");
}

private void stopRecording() {
    LOG_TAG = "stopRecording";
    recorder.stop();

    if (startRecThread != null && startRecThread.isAlive()) {
        startRecThread.destroy();
        startRecThread = null;
    }

    player.stop();
    player.flush();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "stop Recording");
}

private void stop() {
    if (isRecording) {
        isRecording = false;
        stopRecording();
    }
    if (isPlaying) {
        isPlaying = false;
        stopPlaying();
    }
    recordBtn.setEnabled(true);
    playBtn.setEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    LOG_TAG = "onCreate";
    // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Create Called");
    // getting the audio service
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

    // creating Buttons one by one . . . .
    // button to start the recording process
    recordBtn = new Button(this);
    recordBtn.setText("Record");
    recordBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            recordBtn.setEnabled(false);
            playBtn.setEnabled(false);
            isRecording = true;
            startRecording();
        }
    });
    // single button to stop recording and playing as applicable
    stopBtn = new Button(this);
    stopBtn.setText("Stop");
    stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            stop();
        }
    });
    // button to play the recorded sound
    playBtn = new Button(this);
    playBtn.setText("Play");
    playBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // reverse the isPlaying
            isPlaying = true;
            recordBtn.setEnabled(false);
            playBtn.setEnabled(false);
            startPlaying();
        }
    });

    ll.addView(recordBtn, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

    ll.addView(playBtn, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

    ll.addView(stopBtn, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

    setContentView(ll);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Clean up code . ..
    super.onDestroy();
    if (recorder != null)
        recorder.release();
    if (startRecThread != null && startRecThread.isAlive())
        startRecThread.destroy();
    if (recorder != null)
        recorder.release();
    if (player != null)
        player.release();
    startRecThread = null;
    recorder = null;
    player = null;
    recordBtn = null;
    stopBtn = null;
    playBtn = null;
    audioData = null;
    System.gc();
}

}
```

Here is the error LOGCAT file.....

```
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at audio.xxx.com.Audio_testActivity.startRecording(Audio_testActivity.java:232)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at audio.xxx.com.Audio_testActivity.access$9(Audio_testActivity.java:194)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at audio.xxx.com.Audio_testActivity$3.onClick(Audio_testActivity.java:291)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-17 09:53:01.402: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Let me know where I am wrong.. Help me Please.!!!!!!!!!

Comment: line no.81 in Audio_testActivity.java ?

Comment: please let us know ine no.81 in Audio_testActivity.java because import statement are missing from your file so we can't get that.

Comment: @DheereshSingh -- updated with IMPORT .. please let me know the solution. Thanks

Comment: Thanks rahul but I meant to say that please let us know the line no.81 in Audio_testActivity.java in your IDE when you got error...

Comment: are you getting this statement in your log before error "Problem inside init function" ?

Comment: yup.. I am getting before init(). let me know where line 81 code should be return.

Comment: I have place line81 code in startrecording method at line184. please check out. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are getting the "Problem inside init function" and from your code

```
if (recorder != null && player != null) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "recorder and player initialized");
        audioData = new short[recorderBufSize / 2]; // since we r reading
                                                    // shorts

    } else {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem inside init function ");
    }
```

recorder may be null. Please check that.

Comment: this log "Problem inside init function" is coming?

Comment: no its not coming in INIT().. I have added 81-line code in startrecording function.  now error in startrecording function.

Comment: sorry but why you did this " I have added 81-line code in startrecording function. now error in startrecording function." ? we just want to know line no 81 code.

Comment: Seems like you had better check that *recorder* is non-null before you try to call any of its methods.  If it is null, you will need to either initialize it or give up on the current operation as appropriate.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I tried that.. recorder is not null.. please can you help me out.. thanks