# Live Recording and Playing in android latency issue

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I am using [Live Audio Recording and Playing in Android and Thread & callback handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413998/live-audio-recording-and-playing-in-android-and-thread-callback-handling) this example for recording over play back but there is very little latency while the recorded audio is played back. how to solve it.

```
boolean m_isRun=true;
public void loopback() {
        // Prepare the AudioRecord & AudioTrack
        try {
            buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            if (buffersize <= BUF_SIZE) {
                buffersize = BUF_SIZE;
            }
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Initializing Audio Record and Audio Playing objects");

            m_record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize * 1);

            m_track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
                    SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize * 1,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            m_track.setPlaybackRate(SAMPLE_RATE);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error", "Initializing Audio Record and Play objects Failed "+t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        m_record.startRecording();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Audio Recording started");
        m_track.play();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Audio Playing started");

        while (m_isRun) {
            m_record.read(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE);
            m_track.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "loopback exit");
    }

    private void do_loopback() {
        m_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                loopback();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by Opensl of Android. But Android working to achieve it.

Below are the few tutorial that will help you

https://code.google.com/p/opensl-soundpool/

https://code.google.com/p/high-performance-audio/